# color list-items from a range of colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a two colors `rgb(255, 0, 255)` and `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

I also have an unordered list with x number og list-items.

I need to give all the list-items a background split equaly between that range of colors.

For instance

```
first li: rgb(255, 0 ,255)
second li: rgb(255, 0 ,127)
third li: rgb(255, 0 ,63)
fourth li: rgb(255, 0 ,0)
```

This example is very simplified and I need to do it in away so the code will work with any color range.

How would I go about this please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $( 'ul' ).each( function(){
        var lis = $( this ).children( 'li' ),
            l          = lis.length,
            color_from = [ 255, 0, 255 ],
            color_to   = [ 255, 0, 0 ];
        lis.each( function(i){
            var c = [],j=0;
            for ( ; j < 3; ++j )
                c[j] = Math.floor( color_from[j]*(l-i)/l + color_to[j]*(i)/l );
            $( this ).css( "background-color", 'rgb(' + c.join(',') + ')' );
        } );
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/89en4/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i would I go about it if all 3 values in rgb changes?

Comment: Just change the `color_from` and `color_to` values. I.e. `color_from = [ 255, 255, 255 ], color_to = [ 0, 0, 0 ];` (or whatever color values you want to change between).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, but maybe this?
`ul li ul{-webkit-linear-gradient:(rgb(255,0,255),rgb(255,0,0))}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, for simplicity:

```
function colorRange(elems){
    var from = from || 255,
        to = to || 0,
        steps = Math.floor(from/elems.length);
    elems.css('background-color', function(i){
        return 'rgb(255, 0,' + (from - (i*steps)) + ')';
    });
}

colorRange($('li'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bSMn7/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this  [stuff](http://i2ui.com):

HTML:

```
<ul data-i2="css:[{backgroundColor:'rgb(255, 0, 255)'},{backgroundColor:'rgb(255, 0, 0)'}]">
    <li data-i2="rate:1">first</li>
    <li data-i2="rate:2">second</li>
    <li data-i2="rate:3">third</li>
    <li data-i2="rate:4">fourth</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    i2.emph();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59cen/2/)